# ReactJS - Embed Svg image using D3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am using react + webpack + d3.

I am building a dynamic SVG graph using D3.
I can add image an `SVG` as follows in react:

```
import file_1 from '../../icons/03_file_reg.svg';

<image src={file_1}... />
```

This works. But I am trying to figure out how to do it with `D3`:

```
<svg id="test_svg">

</svg>  

d3.select("#test_svg").append("image").attr("xlink:href", {file_1}).attr("width", 10)....
```

This doesn't work.

I have seen another way to do it like so: [how to use svg file for image source in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975929/how-to-use-svg-file-for-image-source-in-d3)

but his forces me to use static path to my svg instead of importing. is this the only way to do it? or can i use import some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with imported SVGs as well:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from 'd3';

import SVGImage from './assets/example.svg';

const D3Image = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select('#my-svg');
    svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", SVGImage)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
  });

    return (
      <svg id="my-svg"></svg>
    );

}

export default D3Image;
```

with other words: get rid of the curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

i think you can try append a tag before href

```
d3.select("#test_svg").append("a").attr("xlink:href", {file_1}).attr("width", 10)
```